# What does comma in CSS definition mean

Tags: css

What does this type of CSS definition mean? Note the first two classes are separated without comma but the last two are separated with comma.

```
.Container .layout, .groupContainer
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question here. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma separates selectors allowing one group of CSS styles to apply to multiple different groups. In your posted CSS:

```
.Container .layout,
.groupContainer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

`width: 100%` will be applied to elements of class `layout` within elements of class `Container`, and to elements with the `groupContainer` class.

References:

- [CSS: 'Groups of Selectors'](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping).

Answer (score 4):

It is shortcut of

```
.groupContainer
{
   width: 100%;
}
.Container .layout
{
   width: 100%;
}
```

You should use it to group your CSS

Answer (score 2):

As explained above, it helps group single CSS declarations across multiple selectors, and can help save file size (which could come in very handy as your CSS file gets larger!) and make things a bit clearer to read.

For example, you could have multiple selectors with the same declarations:

```
.div1 {
    color: red;
}
.div2 {
    color: red;
}
.div3 {
    color: white;
}
.div4 {
    color: white;
}
```

And you can shorten this by using:

```
.div1,.div2 {
    color: red;
}
.div3,div4 {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make more sense as a comment if it is just adding to the other answers?

Comment: Why haven't you said that to any of the other answers?

Comment: In fairness, it would be difficult to provide that much code - legibly - in the comment-space.

Comment: And because I feel as though my answer provides something much more important than no answers have (about the file size).

Comment: @Lee I was just saying that since you were specifically referencing the other answers, it may make more sense as a comment. What was added could fit inside a comment since the difference between your two examples was already demonstrated. It was in no way intentionally malicious or rude, so please don't take it as such. I was just making a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The **comma** is used for grouping, when the same rule applies for several selectors. Each selector is completely independent of the others.

The **space** is used for select any **.layout** that are inside **.container**, even if there are other elements between them.

For your question, the answer is:

you grouping **.layout** which is inside the **.container** class and **.groupContainer** for both the width value is 100%.